# how can i obtain the output of a subprocess in java

Tags: java, android, subprocess

maybe it has some connection with android, but not much IMO.

```
    package com.main.app;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class RootPermissionActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        try {
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
            DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());
            outputStream.writeBytes("touchasd /m\n");

                       //codes below used to get the error output, but get nothing.
            TextView suCommandMessage = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.suCommandMessage);
            BufferedReader d = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
              String msg;
              while((msg = d.readLine()) != null) {
                  suCommandMessage.setText(msg);
              }

            outputStream.writeBytes("exit \n");
            p.waitFor();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                           .setTitle("Exception")
                           .setMessage("IOException: " + e)
                           .setPositiveButton("OK", null)
                           .show();
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
               .setTitle("Exception")
               .setMessage("InterruptedException: " + e)
               .setPositiveButton("OK", null)
               .show();
        }
    }
}
```

first i create a new process `su` to gain the root permission, it's just a sub-process to run shell command, then i write some codes to the sub-process, everything is OK. then i want to gain the error output of the sub-process, so i write a wrong command `touchasd /m\n`, but i dont know how to gain the error output of the sub-process, can anyone give a hand to me ? thx. :)

Answer (score 0):

Do something like the following to get the error stream of the process.

```
BufferedReader stdErr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
```

I didnt see the comments in your code block it seems that the above line and related stuff are commented out in your code block.

Comment: Oh, what i wrote at the very start may mislead you. i have edited it just now. in fact, some codes have been commented out only indicate that they dont work.